# mirroring the screen of my 1020 to a TV supports this without internet

Tags: nokia-lumia-1020, project-my-screen

How I can mirror my Lumia 1020 screen to a TV that supports screen mirroring without internet and without hardware adittion?
My 1020 on Cyan WP version
Thx

Answer (score 0):

If you go into **settings** -> **project my screen** You'll see a message that says:

> This phone can't project your screen with a wireless connection, but you an se a USB cable to connect to a Windows device.

Whilst it was [suggested that the Lumia 1020 *could* support Miracast](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/3566/106), it's apparent that this is not yet the case, even with the Denim update.