# Project my screen doesn't detect windows 10 pc

Tags: windows-10, project-my-screen

I have Windows 10 installed on my pc. I want to project my Windows 8.1 Lumia 720 screen on my pc. How would I do that? I have connected both the devices with USB but no device is found or listed in the mobile settings `project my screen`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/3540/how-to-use-project-my-screen-in-windows-phone-8-1

Comment: @RowlandShaw, it's not duplicate. It's related to Windows 10 PC. I am also having the same issue.

Comment: @NK I'd read the other question as the general case - there's nothing in this question that explains why the answer there can't be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these steps:

1. Connect your Lumia
2. Open device manager on your PC
3. Uninstall the drivers for your phone.

[image]

4. Disconnect your windows mobile
5. Restart your PC and Windows mobile
6. Reconnect your phone.

---

**Update:**

If these steps didn't work try connecting your phone via a USB 2.0 port instead of a USB 3.0 port. See [this post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia-mdsettings/project-my-screen-on-lumia-950-xl/4cfba826-2027-48f0-932e-7c6d59459c06?auth=1) in Microsoft Comunity for further reference.

Answer (score 3):

You must download the PC [Project My Screen App](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42536). Then when you plug your phone into your PC it should automatically detect it.

Comment: It doesn't detect my device. I have the app in pc.

Comment: Can you see the device in File Explorer?

Comment: Yes I can see the see the device in file explorer

Comment: Have you manually started the PC app while the phone is connected?

Comment: Yes I manually started the Windows app

Comment: @Shawn, are you able to use the App in Windows 10?

Comment: @NK PC or Mobile?

Comment: @Shawn, PC I mean. My case is  PC Running on Win10 & Mobile running on Win8.1 Update

Comment: @NK It works for me.