# Is there a way we can share mobile screen

Tags: screen, sharing

Is there a way we can share mobile screen with windows mobile or android. Currently i am using windows 8.1 and Nokia Lumia 620.

Comment: Do you want to share your mobile screen to an another mobile?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone 8.1 supports sharing the screen [to Mircast devices (where the phone is compatible - not sure if the 620 is), or over USB to desktop PCs running the Project My Screen app](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/3540/106).

I'm [not aware of a phone acting as a Miracast receiver](http://www.wi-fi.org/product-finder-results?capabilities=2), so you might not be able to share screen from phone to phone

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can but only when your device connected with PC or TV using USB cable. Download and Install this [app](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42536) on your PC, connect your phone with PC and you will get Pop Up Message on your phone to project the screen or not.