# Does Windows Phone 8.1 suppport Chromecast 2

Tags: 8.1, nokia-lumia-625, project-my-screen

I have a Nokia Lumia 625 and it is updated to Windows Phone 8.1. In settings it also has a "Project my Screen" option.

If I buy a Chromecast 2 device, will I be able to cast videos or the phone's screen to a TV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.**

The "Project my screen" feature in Windows Phone uses the [Miracast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracast) standard. It's not compatible with Chromecast, which uses a different technology altogether.

If you want to stream media from your phone to your TV, you should get a Miracast adapter. I'd recommend the [Microsoft Wireless Display Adapter](https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/accessories/wireless-display-adapter-2), but there are other options as well.

For more information, see [How to use Project my screen in Windows Phone 8.1?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/3540/1401)